# How to calculate min value of a string from a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm a beginner in Python and I want to find out how to calculate the min/max, mean, median values from a csv file. Note, without using the csv module, or any of the sort. I just want to use the 'reading/opening files' method.

So after putting in the code to read the file, this is what I've written (I wanted to read only the second column of the file):

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as x:
            second = []
            for line in x:
                spl = [float(data.split(',')[1]) for data in x]
                second.append(spl[0:6])
            print(second)

            lowest = min(second)
            print(lowest)
```

When I execute this, Python prints out two statements (of the second column, like what I wanted) but prints out, for example `[x, y, z]` instead of actually calculating the min value.

When I tried omitting the `float` part in the line `spl = [...]` Python just executes the same thing but `['x','y','z']` instead (with quotation marks).

Comment: @Pedro Lobito sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you share a sample line of `data.csv`. Without a **clear** sample,  it's difficult to help you.

Comment: @coconutjeon: it's because your `second` is a list of lists, try to concatenate instead of appending.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito The file just contains headings for the first row and first column (ie words), and floating point numbers for the rest. The code I wrote above executes the second column (excluding the heading for that column) which is a list of numbers.

Comment: try to concatenate directly: `second += spl[0:6]`

Comment: Do you need to get the high,low, etc, for each line or the whole file?

Comment: @Pedro Lobito the min, max of a column.

Comment: @SuperKogito that helped! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You only need to append a single item to `second`, and you don't need `[... for data in x]` around your float if you only want the second item (`[1]`)

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as x:
            second = []
            for line in x:
                spl=float(line.split(',')[1])
                second.append(spl)
            print(second)

            lowest = min(second)
            print(lowest)
```

outputs:

```
$ ./minVal.py
[124.0, 32.0, 663.0, 3.0, 6234.0, 73.0, 7.0]
3.0
```

Comment: I tried that, but now it reads the headings of my csv file (ie. words) when I want it to just read the numbers. The numbers start in the 2nd column, 2nd row. My headings are in the first row and first column.

Comment: So then do some very basic error handling, add `if line.split(',')[1].isdigit():` below the `for` loop and indent `spl=float(line.split(',')[1])` and `second.append(spl)`

Answer (score 0):

> *(I need) the min, max of a column*

---

To find the `min` and `max` of a column in a csv file, without using any imports, you can try:

```
with open("stack_csv_max_val.csv", "r") as f:
    s = f.readlines()

ls =  [x for x in [x.strip().split(",") for x in s]]
results = {}
for l in ls:
    ll = [float(x) for x in l]
    for f in range(0, len(ll)):
        if not f in results:
            results[f] = {"min": 1000000, "max": 1}
        if ll[f] > results[f]['max']:
            results[f]['max'] = ll[f]
        elif ll[f] < results[f]['min']:
            results[f]['min'] = ll[f]

print(results)
# print(results[3]) # min/max of column 4
```

---

I.e: `file.csv`

```
1,6,8,10
2,19,56,45
3,6,9,11
5,6,9,22
```

---

I.e. output:

```
{0: {'max': 5.0, 'min': 1},
 1: {'max': 19.0, 'min': 6},
 2: {'max': 56.0, 'min': 8},
 3: {'max': 45.0, 'min': 10}}
```

---

Notes:

1. I'm sure there are easier ways without imports, this is just one way
   of doing it.
2. The code above assumes all numbers in the csv are `> 0`
3. [Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/c8d43c4725)